# Gaussian process in linear regression

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, gaussian-process

I am looking for papers that establish a linear regression fit through modeling regression errors as a Gaussian process . Any good literature ?

Comment: The usual assumption is the error terms are independent Gaussian and not a general Gaussian process.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, the standard assumption in linear regression is well known. I am looking for models similar to the random effects models, were errors have non-diagonal elements in the covariance matrix. Specifically I am searching literature than handles errors as a correlated stochastic process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modeling linear regression with Gaussian process errors have been well studied in literature. These works are mostly based on Blight and Ott (1975) who modeled residuals of some basis functions in linear regression as a GP. Also refer to Rasmussen's book [Chapter 2](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf) section 2.7 for a detailed discussion and additional references.